# Importar CSV a SQL SERVER error tildes y eñes

Tags: sql-server, csv, acentos

Estoy intentando subir mis ficheros de csv a SQl Server. Se me importa correctamente pero cuando hago una consulta a estos ficheros importados, los acentos y eñes aparecen con simbolo raro, ¿ cómo puedo hacer para qué me respete mis tildes y eñes? Muchas gracias, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido isayoyo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Cómo estas importando el archivo (indicalo en tu pregunta)? también verifica con que codificación fue salvado el CSV. Saludos.

Comment: Es importante saber que estás usando para saber como corregirlo. Porque hay muchas formas de subir csv a SQL Server.